# Python requests with certificates

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, certificate

I am trying to get the sandbox of HSBC's Open Banking to work. The curl command from their [documentation](https://developer.hsbc.com/#/apiCatalogue/obie_accountInformation/documentation/introduction) gives me a access token only when I disable verification with `-k`. Note that I downloaded the `xyz.der` and `server.key` from my HSBC developer [dashboard](https://developer.hsbc.com/#/dashboard).

```sh
curl -v -k -X POST \
--cert hsbc/qwac_PSP_PI,PSP_AS,PSP_IC,PSP_AI_27_10_2020.der \
--cert-type DER \
--key hsbc/server.key \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-H "Accept: application/json" \
-H "x-fapi-financial-id: test" \
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" \
-d 'grant_type=client_credentials&scope=accounts&client_assertion_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer&client_assertion=xyz' \
"https://sandbox.hsbc.com/psd2/obie/v3.1/as/token.oauth2"
```

Since this is working I am trying to do the same with `requests` but am struggling in how to use the certificates. I know `requests` supports the `cert` keyword but it seems I would need to add the other parameters too. Is there a way I can specifics the certificate type and corresponding key?

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "x-fapi-financial-id": "test",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
}
params = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "accounts",
    "client_assertion_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
    "client_assertion": "xyz",
}
url = "https://sandbox.hsbc.com/psd2/obie/v3.1/as/token.oauth2"

requests.post(url=url,
              headers=headers,
              params=params,
              cert="hsbc/qwac_PSP_PI,PSP_AS,PSP_IC,PSP_AI_27_10_2020.der",
              verify=False).json()
```

Comment: You seem to have some private data in there ('client_assertion').  Please remove it and replace it with something else

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it was necessary because it is a sandbox. I have removed it now.

Comment: Convert your cert and key to PEM format with `openssl` and supply `cert=` as a tuple `(cert, key)` or put both in one file.

Comment: @KlausD. that worked fine indeed. Thanks! Does `requests` always expect the `.pem` format?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @KlausD. this works now after converting the `.der` to `.pem` with `openssl`:

```sh
openssl x509 -inform der -in qwac_xyz.der -out qwac_xyz.pem
```

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "x-fapi-financial-id": "test",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
}
params = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "accounts",
    "client_assertion_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:client-assertion-type:jwt-bearer",
    "client_assertion": "xyz",
}
url = "https://sandbox.hsbc.com/psd2/obie/v3.1/as/token.oauth2"

requests.post(url=url,
              headers=headers,
              params=params,
              cert=("hsbc/qwac_xyz.pem", "hsbc/server.key"),
              verify=False).json()
```